# How to fetch inner API data in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I am trying to do is fetch the inner data of `blog_set`. But in my case, I'm getting a `null` value (usually nothing is output).
Is this the correct way to get the value: `{bloglist.blog_set.title}` ?

api-data:

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/category/brown",
        "id": 1,
        "title": "brown",
        "slug": "brown",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/category/bg_1.jpg",
        "description": "",
        "created_on": "2020-05-08T15:21:02Z",
        "status": true,
        "blog_set": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/blog_detail/test3",
                "title": "test3",
                "slug": "test3",
                "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/blog/author.jpg",
                "description": "test3",
                "created_on": "2020-05-13T13:36:45Z",
                "status": true,
                "category": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

./src/Category.js

```
export default class App extends Component{
 state = {
    bloglist: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/category");
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      this.setState({ bloglist: jsonResponse });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render(){
        {
    const { bloglist } = this.state;

    return(
        <div>
        {bloglist.map((bloglist) => (
            <div>

                        <h3 class="mb-2">{bloglist.blog_set.title}</h3>

            </div>
            ))}
        </div>

        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are u sure that fetching of localhost can be done in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bloglist is also an array you need to use one more `.map()` or as `bloglist[0].blog_set[0].title`

Example:

```
{bloglist.map((bloglist) => (
    <div>
        <h3 class="mb-2">{bloglist.blog_set.map(i=> i.title)}
        </h3>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: He has already mapping over bloglist, so `bloglist[0]` is nonsense

Comment: hey there, can you please take a look at this link? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61908356/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-after-successful-login-in-reactjs

Answer (score 2):

`blog_set` is an array so it does not have an attribute/memeber/item called `title`. You should define at what index you want the data.

```
bloglist.blog_set[0].title
```

Or iterate over `blog_set` too

Answer (score 1):

`blog_set` is an array. In order to iterate it, use `map` and `{title}`. In each iteration of your `blog_set` object, there is a key named `title` (destructured object).

```
<div>
    {bloglist.map((bloglist) => (
        <div>   
            <h3 class="mb-2">{blog_set.map(({title})=>title))}</h3>    
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @SherylHohman Thanks for the suggestion/comment, I have added description for the solution posted.

Comment: hey there.... please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701259/how-to-use-search-effect-in-reactjs    . Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

blogList.map() will iterate the parent Array of objects to get blog_set and blog_set.map() will now iterate the blog_set to get list title

```
 {bloglist.map((bloglist) =>(
  <div>
    <h3 class="mb-2">{bloglist.blog_set.map((list)=>( list.title)}</h3>

        </div>)}
```

Comment: this would be `<h3 class="mb-2">{bloglist.blog_set.map((list)=>( list.title))}</h3>` . thanks, anyways it helped!

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation